# Should we merge autostart and startup-applications tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retag-request

In my opinion, both the tags deal with making an application start automatically upon logging in. I believe they should be made synonyms of each other and possibly, even merged together.

Here's the breakdown of the two tags:

- [autostart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/autostart) x 91
- [startup-applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/startup-applications) x 46

If anyone has any other contradictory thoughts to my opinion, I would be glad to entertain them.

Comment: I agree. Who can do that?

Answer (score 4):

I agree, as programs to be started based on time should be [cron](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cron). Looking at [autostart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/autostart), it appears that tag is for the purpose of startup applications.